# Ideas on how to model categorial variable with varying combination of values?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I am doing an interesting data mining project just to get my hands dirty with machine learning techniques. The data I am using is scraped from IMDB and I am trying to construct a supervised learning technique in order to predict the IMDB score (for more information - https://www.kaggle.com/deepmatrix/imdb-5000-movie-dataset).
In this data film genre has been extracted as well and the values look like this:

```
Action
Action|Adventure
Action|Adventure|Animation|Comedy|Crime|Family|Fantasy
Adventure|Horror
```

So - one movie can be describe with only one genre and another with multiple (up to 8). Furthermore the combinations may vary greatly.

I am wondering what feature engineering would be appropriate so that we can model this object. The simplest way of doing it, as I though, was to extract just the first genre listed and use that as a predictor. But are there any techniques that allows us to use this combinations? Note that I have already split this one genre variable into multiple variables depending on how many genres have been listed.
Just if someone's interested here's how I split the variable in R:

```
max(str_count(movies.all$genres,"\\|")) #7 occurances of | => meaning maximum 8 genres listed
temp <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(movies.all$genres,"\\|",8))
```

**Update**

```
#I have manually check (using excel) the unique list of genres

all.genres.list<-c("Action",                   "Adventure",
                   "Animation",                   "Biography",
                   "Comedy",                   "Crime",
                   "Documentary",                   "Drama",
                   "Family",                   "Fantasy",
                   "Film-Noir",                   "Game-Show",
                   "History",                   "Horror",
                   "Music",                   "Musical",
                   "Mystery",                   
                   "Romance",                   "Sci-Fi",
                   "Short",                   "Sport",
                   "Thriller",                   "War",
                   "Western")

sparse.matrix.genre<-matrix(nrow = nrow(movies.all),ncol = length(all.genres.list))
colnames(sparse.matrix.genre)<-all.genres.list

#create the dummies
for (i in 1:length(all.genres.list))
{
      sparse.matrix.genre[,i]<-ifelse(grepl(all.genres.list[i], movies.all$genres)==TRUE,1,0)
}

#review frequency
apply(sparse.matrix.genre,2,sum,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: The genre can be seen as several binary variables instead of a single categorical one. Using only the first one makes no sense though, as they appear to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: +1 for firebug (you should  also inform yourself about bag of words and sparse matrices - you can cope with even 1000s of category instances using these)

Comment: to be explicit, create a binary variable for each possible genre, e.g. 50 ( of which no more than 8 occur in any one movie).  So you have a N x 50 matrix.  sparse matrices are just ways of storing the data in memory efficient way, but in a matrix format supported by some ML tools e.g. glint

Comment: This morning I was thinking about dummufication as well. Thanks - I will spend some time reading about bag of words and sparse matrices. Now I will try doing the technical part of converting this "|"-separated field to dummies. Will write you my approach later